# Passing parameters to methods in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following method in my Posts Controller:

```
public function index( $filter = null )
{
    debug($filter); exit;
}
```

If I visit the following URL: `/posts/index/filter:test` it will return null but If I use `/posts/index/test` it will return test...

I was under the impression that Cake treated passed parameters as named by default?

I tried fixing this using a route like:

`Router::connect('/test', array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'index','filter'=>'test'));`

But it still came back as null! As though the filter doesn't get passed to the method...

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

if you need to get the named parameter, you can use the params property of the controller:

```
$this->params['named']['filter']
```

Comment: But is it even a named parameter?

Comment: when you pass it to the url like this: /index/filter:value - it is named.

Comment: So why isn't my method picking it up?

Comment: because your first argument `$filter` is the PASSED argument number 1 (just as the documentation states and it always has been)